# Compile Hex-Rays code

Tags: decompilation, hexrays

I'm aware, that Hex-Rays provides pseudocode, which is not supposed to be compiled, but I'm trying to do it.

So far I stopped on instructions like that:

```
char (__usercall *__fastcall sub_947770(__int64 a1, __int64 a2))@<al>(__int64 a1@<rdx>, __m128i *a2@<xmm6>);
```

Those @< a1 > a1@< rdx >, etc are not recognizable by MSVC 2015 compiler. Is  there any way to compile this code or to setup decompilation options to generate something more compiler-friendly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this line to:

char * FASTCALL sub_947770(int64 a1, int64 a2)

Comment: Would be nice to understand, what's hidden under this HexRays notation. Do you have some links?

Comment: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1361.shtml